# problems solved by the worst fit

Tags: memory

What are the problems that have been solved by  worst fit ?
why need to use worst fit ?

Answer (score 1):

All the fit strategies have their own advantages.
Consider an example:
Suppose a process requests 12KB of memory and the memory-manager currently has 13KB and 19KB of fixed memory, then if you go by worst-fit, 12KB of 19KB will be used up leaving 7KB left for other processes, but in best-fit, 12KB of 13KB would be used leaving only 1KB of free memory which will rarely come in use for any process.